# Tensorflow with CUDA 8.0 rc

Tags: nvidia, cuda

When I try to import tensorflow in Python, I get this error.

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using CUDA 8.0 RC and Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 you have to build and install TF from source, during configuration phase it will request CUDA version, specify 8.0

Answer (score 0):

As it says on [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html) docs, you should normally install CUDA via pip, and then the tensorflow package as it says.
Then there is an activation, before use.

```
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate  # If using bash.
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate.csh  # If using csh.
(tensorflow)$  # Your prompt should change.
# Run Python programs that use TensorFlow.
...
# When you are done using TensorFlow, deactivate the environment.
(tensorflow)$ deactivate
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just remove cuda 8.0 and install cuda 7.5 which I did. Remove cuda 8.0 -

```
sudo dpkg -r cuda
```

Download cuda 7.5 from nvidia website. Then, do-

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, got to synaptic packet manager, and search for `cuda`. Select `cuda-7-5`, and install everything associated. You have to do it from synaptic packet manager. If you do `sudo apt-get install` from terminal, it will again install cuda 8.0.

Hope this saves someone from pulling hair out of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have CUDA 8.0 but your libcudart seems to be version 7.5. You might need to remove CUDA and start over, `rm -rf /usr/local/cuda-<7.5 or 8.0>` Make sure to replace the <> section with your actual version(s) and run it as `sudo`. After you do a fresh install, create a .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/:

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf`

Add this:

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib  # you probably don't need this line; check
                         # if the directory exists
```

Then run `sudo ldconfig`. Hope this brings you joy.